# Protobuf-net RuntimeTypeModel not serializing members of base class

Tags: protobuf-net

Say I have the following base class:

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public abstract class DimensionEntity
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    private readonly Date effectiveDatespan;
    ...
}
```

And the following derived class:

```
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class ClearingSite : DimensionEntity
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    private readonly string code;
    ...
}
```

When I serialize an instance of `ClearingSite` as follows:

```
        model.Add(typeof(ClearingSite), true);
        model.Serialize(ms, clearingSite);
```

I can see that only the `code` member of `ClearingSite` is serialized; the value of the base class' `effectiveDatespan` member is not serialized.

Two notes:

1. I can see that the `BaseType` member of the added `ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType` is set to `null`, causing the `effectiveDatespan` member to not be serialized; if I compile the model, instead, its `BaseType` member is correctly set to `DimensionEntity` (though it fails later on as the members are `private readonly` and thus not accessible by a compiled model);
2. Of course I can declare `ClearingSite` as a known type of `DimensionEntity`, but I can't see why this would be required: I am not serializing a `DimensionEntity`, I'm serializing (and de-serializing) a `ClearingSite`, and furthermore the `DataContractSerializer` does not require me to add `KnownType` to `DimensionEntity` if I'm serializing a `ClearingSite`.

From other answers from Marc, it looks like Protobuf would require the `KnownType` (or `ProtoInclude`) attribute in order to get the "all-important field-number" (quote), but that seems to not be the case, as the `CompiledModel` works totally fine without `ProtoInclude`.

Note that I'm striving to use `System.Runtime.Serialization` attributes only, as I'm trying to keep my object model unaware of serializers down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProtoInclude, or an equivalent, is definitely required. If something is happening oddly with the compiled version, then that is a bug and I can investigate.

If you don't want to add non-BCL attributes to your type, this can be done at runtime:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(BaseType)]
    .AddSubClass(.....);
```

(or somethig like that - I'm not at a PC)

Comment: Thanks Marc. Which drawbacks would you see if one implemented a helper function that upon adding type `T` to the model would visit the hierarchy _path_ from `T` to `object` and for each type `Ti` marked as `DataContract` would automagically `Add(typeof(Ti)).AddSubClass(T)`?

Comment: @Gabriele the only problem I have with "automagically" is that the **number** is important, and you need to be able to reliably get   **the same number** in the future, even when extra types have been added to the system, and things have been renamed. If you can do that: fine.