# Protobuf-net RuntimeTypeModel with inherited private fields fails, ProtoInclude attribute on base class works

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

If I have a test setup as

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(DecoratorDerived))]
public class DecoratorBase
{
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    private int baseValue1;

    private int baseValue2;

    public DecoratorBase()
    {
        baseValue1 = (new Random()).Next();
        baseValue2 = (new Random()).Next();
    }

    protected void ShowBaseValue()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"DecoratorBase - baseValue1: {baseValue1}, baseValue2: {baseValue2}");
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class DecoratorDerived : DecoratorBase
{
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int derivedValue1;

    private int derivedValue2;

    public DecoratorDerived()
    {
        derivedValue1 = (new Random()).Next();
        derivedValue2 = (new Random()).Next();
    }

    public void ShowValues()
    {
        ShowBaseValue();
        Console.WriteLine($"DecoratorDerived - derivedValue1: {derivedValue1}, derivedValue2: {derivedValue2}");
    }
}

    static void DecoratorTest()
    {
        var c1 = new DecoratorDerived();
        c1.ShowValues();

        byte[] raw;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize<DecoratorDerived>(stream, c1);
            raw = stream.ToArray();
        }

        DecoratorDerived c2;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(raw))
        {
            c2 = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<DecoratorDerived>(stream);
        }
        c2.ShowValues();
    }
```

Everything works fine but the real-world issue is that my classes derived from the base are auto-generated via T4 and there is a lot of them so adding all the `ProtoInclude` lines is not workable. Doing some research showed doing things on the fly with RuntimeTypeModel. So changing the test to

```
[ProtoContract]
public class RTMBase
{
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    private int baseValue1;

    private int baseValue2;

    public RTMBase()
    {
        baseValue1 = (new Random()).Next();
        baseValue2 = (new Random()).Next();
    }

    protected void ShowBaseValue()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"RTMBase - baseValue1: {baseValue1}, baseValue2: {baseValue2}");
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class RTMDerived : RTMBase
{
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int derivedValue1;

    private int derivedValue2;

    public RTMDerived()
    {
        derivedValue1 = (new Random()).Next();
        derivedValue2 = (new Random()).Next();
    }

    public void ShowValues()
    {
        ShowBaseValue();
        Console.WriteLine($"RTMDerived - derivedValue1: {derivedValue1}, derivedValue2: {derivedValue2}");
    }
}

    static void RTMTest(RuntimeTypeModel runtimeTypeModel)
    {
        var c1 = new RTMDerived();
        c1.ShowValues();

        // setup RTM, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608767/inheritance-in-protobuf-net-adding-a-lower-base-class-still-backward-compatible
        var myType = runtimeTypeModel[typeof(RTMDerived)];
        var baseType = runtimeTypeModel[typeof(RTMDerived).BaseType];
        if (!baseType.GetSubtypes().Any(s => s.DerivedType == myType))
        {
            foreach (var field in baseType.GetFields())
            {
                myType.Add(field.FieldNumber + 500, field.Name);
            }
        }

        byte[] raw;
        using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize<RTMDerived>(stream, c1);
            raw = stream.ToArray();
        }

        RTMDerived c2;
        using(var stream = new MemoryStream(raw))
        {
            c2 = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<RTMDerived>(stream);
        }
        c2.ShowValues();
    }
```

I get an exception

```
RTMBase - baseValue1: 1874947795, baseValue2: 1391655165
RTMDerived - derivedValue1: 922997568, derivedValue2: 837049520

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Unable to determine member: baseValue1
Parameter name: memberName
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.AddField(Int32 fieldNumber, String memberName, Type itemType, Type defaultType, Object defaultValue) in C:\code\protobuf-net\src\protobuf-net\Meta\MetaType.cs:line 1437
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.Add(Int32 fieldNumber, String memberName) in C:\code\protobuf-net\src\protobuf-net\Meta\MetaType.cs:line 1261
   at proto_error.Program.RTMTest1(RuntimeTypeModel runtimeTypeModel) in /Users/christian/tmp/proto-error/Program.cs:line 52
   at proto_error.Program.Main(String[] args) in /Users/christian/tmp/proto-error/Program.cs:line 17
```

Fortunately for me, changing `RTMBase.baseValue1` to public, protected, or internal makes it work and internal is fine for my use case. But I'm curious if this is a bug or and I doing something wrong?

**ADDENDUM**

If I change the RMTest to

```
static void RTMTest2(RuntimeTypeModel runtimeTypeModel)
{
    var c1 = new RTMDerived();
    c1.ShowValues();

    // setup RTM, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400539/protobuf-net-runtimetypemodel-not-serializing-members-of-base-class
    var baseType = runtimeTypeModel[typeof(RTMDerived).BaseType];
    baseType.AddSubType(500, typeof(RTMDerived));

    byte[] raw;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize<RTMDerived>(stream, c1);
        raw = stream.ToArray();
    }

    RTMDerived c2;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(raw))
    {
        c2 = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<RTMDerived>(stream);
    }
    c2.ShowValues();
}
```

It works just fine but I'm still curious why `RTMRest1` fail. Also, does the 500 parameter need to be different for each type, or can it be a constant?

Answer (score 0):

The key provided is uses to uniquely identify each time as a field in the parent message, so yes: it needs to be different per type **and reliable** - i.e. if it is 500 now, then it also needs to be 500 when you reload that data in two years time.

This also applies *to field numbers*, hence the code shown here is *very* dangerous:

```cs
foreach (var field in baseType.GetFields())
{
    myType.Add(field.FieldNumber + 500, field.Name);
}
```

1. reflection makes no guarantees whatsoever about what *order* it returns things in, breaking the data
2. if someone adds extra fields, it can change the field numbers of *other* fields, breaking the data

As for it not finding the member - I guess it is looking for it as a declared member. That is *possibly* something that could be changed, although it might create ambiguities and brittle scenarios. The following code is entirely valid and compiles fine:

```cs
class Foo
{
    private int a;
}
class Bar : Foo
{
    private int a;
}
```

But the meaning of `"a"` changes depending on whether we're thinking of `Foo` or `Bar`. In your case (resolving base members into derived types), you're thinking of the `Foo.a`, but you'd be asking it to look starting at `Bar`, so the logical thing to resolve would be `Bar.a`. I *think* (from memory) this is why we restrict things to declared members.

Comment: Thanks for responding & for Protobuf-net! Doesn't `field.FieldNumber` represent the `ProtoMember` attribute #? The help text for `FieldNumber` alludes to that. If so, then `myType.Add(field.FieldNumber + 500, field.Name)` is stable unless somebody changes `ProtoMember` indices which seems bad anyway. To clarify, you're saying `baseType.AddSubType(500, typeof(RTMDerived))` wouldn't work in a prod scenario because the "500" needs to be different for each derived class? I understand your "reliable...two years time" but for my usage it's moot since each deploy clears the cache. Thanks again!

Comment: @c17r oh, sorry, yes that's my bad - my apologies. Somehow in my head I saw a `number++` there (i.e. something more like `myType.Add((fieldNumber++) + 500, field.Name);`. You'd be amazed how many times I've seen that!